# How to put an onclick function in wkwebview with loadHTMLString?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, onclick, wkwebview

Basically, I would like to ask how to insert onclick javascript in wkwebview with loadHTMLString? How can I receive the word that I click on wkwebview and pass it to my textfield in swift? I did some researches, some are them are using WKScriptMessageHandler, which I don't really know how to use.

For example,

Apple
Orange
Banana
Watermelon

4 of the fruits are loaded in HTMLString. If I click on Apple, I would like to have 'Apple' in my textfield.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this link https://kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift

Comment: Hi Malik, I tried with the website. Its not working. because I was trying to do everything in 1 page. I appended the string manually. same goes to all javascript function. I inject it in wkwebview did finish load...